# "factorisation" of formulae algorithm

Tags: abstract-algebra, algorithms

I have "expressions" that are loosely analogous to formulae using "+" and "."
("." isnt commutative in my world, but this is a minor wrinkle I think)

e.g.

```
x1.y2 + x1.z2 + y1.z2
```

so I could "factorise" this expression really in 2 ways.

```
x1.(y2 + z2) + y1.z2
```

or

```
x1.y2 + (x1 + y1).z2
```

i.e. I can factorise out by the 2nd value or the 1st.

(obviously if there are many terms in the expression I could do either of these things, and sometimes both)

in fact if i have multiple terms in each terms I can envisage a whole tree of "terminal" (i.e. no further factorisations can occur) expressions can be derived.

Is there any "maths" out there I can apply here?

are there canonical forms? (I can envisage at least 2, one recursively factorisaing out the 1st, then 2nd etc variable in each term, and another the reverse).

Are there any established algorithms?

I can probably formulate an exhaustive tree search algorithm, but it wouldnt scale well.

Comment: It seems your algebra is similar to matrix algebra (since multiplication isn't commutative there either). I think it would help to establish a purpose for the factorization. What makes the factorized expression more appealing to you than the expanded version? That would help guide the choice of algorithm.

Comment: well actually its effective a description of a directed graph, "." is actually "->", so ideally you want the description to be short for humans to comprehend.

Comment: (a + b) -> c
means 
(a -> c) + (b-> c)

you can imagine some networks admit a very short "factorisation" compared to their full expansion

Comment: For the moment I'll write something that either factors from the "source" or factors from the "end" recursively....thats simple, but I suspect not optimal

Comment: actually it seems the "DOT language" is the same as my language, so let me look there

Comment: that didnt help!

Comment: To continue with your example, would you consider the factorisation `(x1 + y1).(y2 + z2) - y1.y2` as well?

Comment: subtraction doesnt exist.

best we drop the "." and use "->", you could extend the language to include removing connections and the "-" would make sense, but I'm not sure i want to go there, there would be a big ripple impact

Comment: Do you want to minimize the number of dot operations? Or what other purpose of factorization do you have?

Comment: errr...well thats a good point, what is optimal?...it needs to be a short as possible, so minimizing "."s would probably do that.

Comment: Are you sure that $\to$ distributes over $+$? Both on the right and on the left? I.e., that in all cases $x \to (y + z) = (x\to y) + (x \to z)$ (left-distributivity) and that $(x + y) \to z = (x \to z) + (y \to z)$ (right-distributivity).

Answer (score 0):

Minimization of the number of dot operations is equivalent to the following graph problem.

Firstly consider a corresponding graph, where every vertex corresponds to variable, and two vertices are adjacent if and only if there is a summand where corresponding variables are dot-operated. Note that this graph is bipartite. And each dot operation corresponds to a *biclique* that is a complete bipartite subgraph, because every summand of the left-hand argument is dot operated by every summand of the right-hand argument.

> [**Definition 51**](https://nagoya.repo.nii.ac.jp/record/19889/files/o7121_thesis.pdf) (The biclique edge partition problem (BEP))**.** The biclique edge partition problem is the problem of finding a set of bicliques $\mathcal B = {B_1, \ldots, B_k}$ of $G$ such that $\mathcal B$ edge-partitions $G$ and $k$ is the minimum.

Thus minimization of the number of dot operations is equivalent to BEP problem of a bipartite graph. This problem is studied well, however I didn't find any result about BEP in bipartite graphs. It is known to be NP-hard for arbitrary graph, even more it is [hard to approximate](https://nagoya.repo.nii.ac.jp/record/19889/files/o7121_thesis.pdf):

> **Theorem 6.** $(6053/6052−\varepsilon)$-approximation of BEP is NP-hard, for arbitrary small $\varepsilon > 0$.

On the other hand there is a new [linear algorithm](https://dspace.ummto.dz/server/api/core/bitstreams/95b882c1-1d0c-4449-955f-21415643dcbe/content) for BEP in distance hereditary bipartite graphs class.

I suppose BEP in bipartite graphs class to be NP-hard, however any result for this question would deserve an article in a mathematical journal.